# How can I create a conditional SUMPRODUCT formula for a horizontal set of timeseries data

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm attempting to use sumproduct on 2 sets of timeseries data that is formatted in the following way:

**Array 1**

```
       | 01/01/2016 | 02/01/2016 | ...
Stock1 | Price1a    | Price1b    |
Stock2 | Price2a    | Price2b    |
```

**Array 2**

```
       | 01/01/2016 | 02/01/2016 | ...
Stock1 | Volume1a   | Volume1b   |
Stock2 | Volume2a   | Volume2b   |
```

Such that for a *given date*, the sumproduct formula will perform price * volume for all stocks in that date.

**Example:**
For 01/01/2016, the formula will return Price1a * Volume1a + Price2a * Volume2a.

Appreciate any help or questions in case it is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the ranges on two different sheets and used this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX($A:$C,2,MATCH(E1,$1:$1,0)):INDEX($A:$C,MATCH("ZZZZ",A:A),MATCH(E1,$1:$1,0)))*(INDEX(Sheet3!$A:$C,2,MATCH(E1,Sheet3!$1:$1,0)):INDEX(Sheet3!$A:$C,MATCH("ZZZZ",Sheet3!A:A),MATCH(E1,Sheet3!$1:$1,0))))
```

The Index/Match define the extents of the arrays.  The tables must have the same number of rows for this to work and the Prices to Volumes must be in the same order.

In the first and third INDEX there is `,2,`.  The `2` is the starting row. If your starting row is different than change it to your starting row number.

The `Match("ZZZ"...` will find the last row with text in it, so make sure there is nothing below the tables.

Also all the `$C` references need to change to the extents of your data.  It can be larger than your data without detriment, so if you just want to set it to something like `$CC` it will be fine.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. Was about to ask the purpose of the "ZZZZ" but I see you already commented!